# Do any words have three or more correct spellings?

Tags: orthography, variants

I can call to mind several words with another correct spelling (colour, analogue, disc, barbeque) but I can't think of any with multiple correct spellings, i.e. three or more equally acceptable, semantically identical variants of the same word. Do any exist?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic firstly because it's a "list" question, and secondly because the definition of "correct" spelling in such contexts is highly subjective.

Comment: I don't see it as a list question, more of a 'does x exist question'. I'd be content with at least one example of a word with multiple variants. If several major dictionaries listed such a word and stated that they are equally acceptable, that would be reasonably objective, no? At least by intersubjectivity.

Comment: Well, OED lists 69 different spellings under its entry for **fairy**. Not all of them *current*, obviously, but I did have to enter **faerie** in a crossword this afternoon, and I wouldn't have fallen off my perch if the answer had actually been **fairie**.

Comment: Wonderful. Which edition? Online or on paper?

Comment: I'd love to see this entry, I can't imagine how a word could have so many variants.

Comment: If you go back for a sufficient number of years, you will find yourself in a wonderful world where *every* word has that many variants.

Comment: Okay, so that's something like a 'yes'. If either of you want to put into an answer with a neat source I'll accept.

Comment: It depends on if you consider an alternate correct spelling just another word.  I don't consider color and colour the same word, so for me the answer is no.  Once it has its own entry in the dictionary, its a new word and can start to pick up its own implications and shades of meaning.

Comment: [ketchup, catsup, catchup](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ketchup?show=0&t=1403655942). [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tomato+catchup%2Ctomato+ketchup%2Ctomato+catsup&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctomato%20catchup%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctomato%20ketchup%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctomato%20catsup%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @PeterShor: post that as an answer?

Comment: Afaik, my name _John_ also has the spellings _Jon_ and _Jhon_. I was a little surprised by the last one, but after all the `H` is silent. I won't go into _Ivan, Ian, Iain, Seán, Séan, Johan, Hans, Giovanni, Juan,_ or _Jean_ -- to refer only to European languages.

Comment: @FumbleFingers [It’s worse than that, sir.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16266232#16266232)

Comment: @JohnLawler Same with *Tom, Thom, Tomm*, although the lattermost seems odd to me, even though it does exist.

Comment: @Oldcat The OED certainly considers *colour* and *color* the same word; you should, too.

Comment: disc does NOT have more than one correct spelling. A disc and a disk are two distinct things. A disc is a throwing disc or a compact disc or any kind of optical media (CD, DVD etc) whereas a disk is magnetic media like a hard drive.

Comment: @JosephNeathawk: So are _stile_ and _style_, but [that didn't help at all](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/style.pdf). Spelling is `Not Official`; sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a four-variant

**aerie/aery/eyrie/eyry**

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/aerie

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eyrie#English

Though some dictionaries only list 3:

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aerie

or 2:

http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/eyrie

Comment: Accepted, though the comments have also been really useful.

Answer (score 8):

There are *ketchup, catsup,* and *catchup,* all in the [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ketchup?show=0&t=1403655942) dictionary. And in fact, looking at [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tomato+catchup%2Ctomato+ketchup%2Ctomato+catsup&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctomato%20catchup%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctomato%20ketchup%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctomato%20catsup%3B%2Cc0), all three spellings were reasonably common between 1910 and 1960, although *catchup* has become relatively rare today.

Comment: All come from Bahasa Melayu _kecap_ /kə'tʃap/ 'sauce'. Foreign words in English spelling come out mutated into several species.

Answer (score -3):

I would say no by definition.

Once you create a new group of letters with a meaning, it is a new word. So fairy - faerie might start out the same, but eventually can acquire shades of meaning and emphasis that differ.  If you say that they are one word, you have to define that this kind of word drift can **never** happen.  I don't think this is possible, so I'm a splitter.

Comment: Consider that *alright*, *all right* and *allright* are common spelling variations (not the greatest of example, but it illustrates my point) all three carry the same meaning. See also  "sense of humor" vs.  "sense of humour", both spellings are recognized and are considered correct, unlike the previous example, where "alright"  is considered to be the standard form. *Humor* is not a new word by virtue of it missing an O, it's just a spelling difference.